# Pass a string array to PL/SQL from Pro*C

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure in a package

```
create or replace package MyPack
  type MyArr is table of varchar2(30) index by pls_integer;

  prodecure MyProc(p in MyArr);
end MyPack;
```

and I want to call it from Pro*C. So I have (all the rest of the function left out)

```
char my_arr[50][30] = {0};

EXEC SQL EXECUTE
  BEGIN
    MyPack.MyProc(:my_arr);
  END;
END-EXEC;
```

When I try to compile this I get the error

"PLS-S-00418, array bind type must match PL/SQL table row type"

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

see [Sample Program 9:  Calling a stored procedure](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/a97269/pc_07pls.htm#i2344)
I think this fits your description.

Comment: It's close, but none of the examples have the type declared in a package, which seems to be confusing the issue somewhat.

Comment: Greg, try to make the declaration using MyPack.MyArr.EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
EXEC SQL my_arr  MyPack.MyArr;

Comment: I did in the end - I will post my solution when I get a bit more time.

Comment: Could you post your solution now as promised? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was trying to pass an c++ array,

```
char names[10][10] = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", ... };
```

to a stored procedure. The solution was to declare the procedure parameter as

```
TYPE NameTab IS TABLE OF CHAR(10) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```